# readv() failed on PROPFIND request while reading php://input (PHP 7, nginx)

Tags: php, curl, nginx, php-7

After upgrading my Server to PHP 7 I get several errors while running ownCloud in its current version 8.1.1.

I tried to figure out what the problem is and I came down to `Sapi.php` of Sabre lib.

I wrote a very small test script to isolate the error. While running the following code using a PROPFIND request, I see errors in the log and I don't get any output out of php://input.

```
<?php 
    fopen("php://input", 'r+');
    echo "Done";
?>
```

Request using cURL:

```
curl -i -X PROPFIND https://cloud.example.com/readv-demo.php  -d 'Demo'
```

Error in nginx error log:

```
*285599 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 5.35.252.37, server: cloud.example.com, request: "PROPFIND /readv-demo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "cloud.example.com"
```

The server worked like a charm using PHP 5.6 and I tried to run PHP 7 without modifications. Everything on server-side is fine but this error.

I also tried suggestions to get around `readv()` errors and modified several settings like:

```
max_input_time = ...
max_execution_time = ...
default_socket_timeout = ...
request_terminate_timeout = ...
```

Comment: I tried now again with a fresh system using nginx 1.9.9 (instead of 1.8.0). Same error message in the logs.

Now I figured out, that using `fopen('php://input')` without read-parameter works. also file_get_contents('php://input') seems to work. This is a workarround for me but I think it is not a solution.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: And, what happens if you replace `PROPFIND` with `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, and `DELETE`?

Comment: Every request method is fine. Only PROPFIND does not work.